Barycentre of a ball
I saw the following definition for the barycentre of a set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
\mathrm{bc}^\Omega=\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)}\int_\Omega x dx \in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$
So I wanted to compute the barycenter for a ball of radius $r$ with center $x_0, \quad \Omega= B_r(x_0)$, and from my understanding it should be $\mathrm{bc}^\Omega=x_0.$
In the Original post my computation was wrong here is the corrected version:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{bc}^\Omega_i&=\frac{1}{\omega_n r^n}\int_0^r\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)}\xi_i dS\xi d\rho\\
  &=\frac{1}{\omega_n r^n}\int_0^r\int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)}|\xi-x_0|\left(\left\langle e_i, \frac{\xi-x_0}{|\xi-x_0|} \right\rangle + \left\langle e_i, \frac{x_0}{|\xi-x_0|} \right\rangle \right) dS\xi d\rho\\
  &=\frac{1}{\omega_n r^n}\int_0^r\rho\int_{B_\rho(x_0)}div(e_i) dx + \int_{\partial B_\rho(x_0)}\rho\left\langle e_i, \frac{x_0}{|\xi-x_0|} \right\rangle dS\xi d\rho\\
  &=\frac{x_{0, i} \cdot n}{r^n}\int_{0}^{r}\rho^{n-1}d\rho=x_{0, i}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Where I first transformed the integral domain to integrate over spheres, then reformulated the integrand to include the unit normal to those spheres. Applied the divergence theorem to the constant $e_i$ and integrated as usual in the second summand.
I also used the formulae:
$$
\int_{B_r(x_0)}1 dx= r^n\omega_n,\quad 
\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)}1 dS\xi= r^{n-1}\omega_n\cdot n
$$
where $\omega_n=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac n2+1)}$ is the volume of the unit ball.

What is $\xi,$ or if it is a vector, what is it doing outside the $dS$ integral?

$\xi$ is the variable for the integration, in this case a vector. It's not outside the integral, one could also write $dS(\xi)$ aswell.

Ah thanks, but then $\xi_i = \left<e_i,\xi\right>$ without dividing by $|\xi-x_0|.$

Oh wow, how could I miss that, yes thanks that was it, I forgot to add that in the nominator.... I guess I shouldn't work on a friday so long :)

So I found the correct derivation, and I'll add it here for completeness, but I'm still curious about where I made the mistake above.
Let us define the Transformation $T(x)=x_0+r\cdot x$, then $det(DT)=r^n$ and so by the transformation formula:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    (\mathrm{bc}^\Omega)_i&=\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)}\int_{T(B_1(0))}x_idx \\
    &= \frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)}\int_{B_1(0)}(x_{0,i}+r\cdot y_i)r^ndy\\
    &=x_{0, i}\frac{r^n \cdot \omega_n}{\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)}+r^{n+1}\int_{B_1(0)}y_idy\\
    &=x_{0,i}+r^{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \rho \xi_i\rho^{n-1}d\xi d\rho=x_{0, i}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In the final equality, we used that the inner integral is $0$ by symmetry, which holds for any monomial of odd power In the final equality, we used that the inner integral is $0$ by symmetry, which holds for any monomial of odd power (cf. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695802)
